# How do you implement GPS using robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a bit new to ROS and I'm unsure how to implement GPS into the project I'm working on. So far I know that I can use robot_localization to get GPS but how would that be implemented ?

Edit 1:

Thanks for the reply,

Yes I have, I've been working on it for a couple of days and it's starting to make sense now. I'm still struggling on some stuff such as how to use the nmea drivers. In the robot_localization tutorials you make a launch file but the nmea wiki it is possible to just use rosrun to get things up and running. Do you first use rosrun to make the connection with the hardware and then launch the launch file to start getting all of the data? Another thing is that I will not be using any odometry data for my localization project. What files do I need to edit so that the code won't be calling for any odometry data?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212702/how-do-you-implement-gps-using-robot_localization/) by [negotiator14](https://answers.ros.org/users/23016/negotiator14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen [this](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration) page? If you have and something isn't clear, please let me know and I'll update it.

EDIT: You might benefit by reading up a little more on [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch). One of the points of `roslaunch` is to save you from having to use `rosrun` and entering a ton of parameters by hand, e.g.,

```
rosrun amazing_package amazing_node param_a:=100 param_b:=true param_c:=-999 param_d:=false
```

Instead, you just create a launch file that kicks off the node and passes in all those parameters. Then you can just launch your launch file instead, e.g.,

```
roslaunch amazing_package amazing_launch_file.launch
```

The state estimation nodes in `robot_localization` do not require an odometry source. `navsat_transform_node` converts GPS data to an odometry *message* so that `ekf_localization_node` or `ukf_localization_node` can consume it. However, if you want to fuse GPS data, you *will* need an IMU with an earth-referenced absolute heading.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5